Copy and Paste in GIMP from one PNG to another is not in the same position
When I right click open a PNG in Gimp and select the upper left corner and copy it with Ctrl+C

And then paste it with Ctrl+V in another PNG, which I also opened in Gimp, it doesn't get pasted in the correct location even though both PNG files are the same size.

How can I ensure it is pasted in the exact same location? Not just when I copy from the corner but from anywhere in the document.

Try Edit > Paste in Place, or use the shortcut Ctrl+Alt+V

@BillyKerr thank you that did the trick! weird though that that isn't default. I don't think anyone needs the weird random position paste.

Well, it's not actually that weird TBH. Many graphics applications have a paste in place option separate from normal pasting for precisely this reason. Also normal pasting isn't random. It pastes in the centre of the canvas.

@BillyKerr normal pasting isn't random. It pastes in the centre of the canvas. Not in Gimp... It paste in the centre of the selection in the target image (which is why Ctrl-C/Ctrl-V pastes exactly above its source). If there is no selection, then this is the centre of the canvas (the usual Select None/Select All equivalence).

@xendoid - yeah I know.  I was really only talking about the OP's situation when pasting from one document into another which has no selection, so it just pastes in the centre, unless of course you employ paste in place instead. Sorry I though it was obvious, but obviously not. ;)
